# Why uninstall did not remove the corresponding folder?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I have just uninstall WampServer because it did not worked (I had 403 error which I could not resolve). After the uninstall is still see "C:\wamp\" directory. Why?

Comment: This directory may have marked to be deleted on reboot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all installers remove all the folders they originally created.

There is a good reason for this - you may value any configuration files you changed that were stored in that folder.

I'm just speculating that this is the reason whoever wrote the installer/uninstaller did it this way.  It could also be a mistake, or any other reason.  If it worries you, just delete the folder.

Comment: +1.  Behaviour of the installer/uninstaller is entirely down to whoever wrote them, and is it really that big a deal anyway?